# Is there a Web API for WeChat?

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, wechat

From what's evident on the [WeChat Developer Site](http://dev.wechat.com/), there is a WeChat API for integrating "WeChat SDK with your iOS and Android apps".

Specifically, I am looking for a way to check to see whether two accounts are friends on WeChat (I have access to the login information for one of those, the other of which varies). Is there a Web API for me to do this with? I was thinking something along the lines of REST, JSON, etc., though I can't seem to find anything of this sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the [Official Account Admin Platform](http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page). I'm not sure about the whole friendship status thing, but that's the closest thing I can find to a WeChat REST API.

Answer (score 2):

I made a code snippet for a python API to read WeChat messages (in a django app)

It also explains how to make a developer account etc

code: https://github.com/tawanda/django-wechat

### Summary

#### Create developer account

- head over to http://admin.wechat.com/debug/sandbox
- Click on Login
- Scan the QR code

You should see the sandbox developer page now